# Gradle is not taking the dependency lock file into account

Tags: gradle, dependencies, locking

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the gradle dependency lock but when building it with

```
gradlew clean build
```

or executing *gradlew test* gradle is not taking the compileClasspath.lockfile which is stored under
*{projectroot}/gradle/dependency-locks*
into account.

I'm using *gradlew dependencies --write-locks* to write the locks. Using gradle version 6.7.1 and tested with 6.8 as well.

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.21.+'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.12.1'
}

group 'xxx'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileClasspath {
        resolutionStrategy.activateDependencyLocking()
    }
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
}

repositories {
    // ...
}

apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/versioning.gradle"
project.version = scmVersion.version
apply plugin: 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.+'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.+'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.6.+'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:6.0.+'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.+'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.+'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.+'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.+'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:2.6.+'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.+'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.+'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.+'
}

test {
    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}

task run(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'Class'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args = ['configuration/dev.properties']
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'Class'
        )
    }
}

project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn project.tasks.shadowJar

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName = "app-standalone"
    archiveClassifier = ''
}
```

I only realized that the locking is now working due to a bug in a dependency. Lock version is 2.6.0 but gradle is taking 2.6.1 which contains the bug. Due due this the tests are failing

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the gradle docs which pointed me to the issue.
Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. I was not locking the test classpath.

It works with the following change:

```
configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
}

dependencyLocking {
    lockAllConfigurations()
}
```

If there is a better way I'm still interested ;)